# If I copy a pointer and then free it, does the original data disappear?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I'm trying to create a linked list in C, and I'm wondering what will happen to `cursor` once I free it.

`cursor` points to the same struct that `head` does, so when I free `cursor` will it also free whatever `head` was pointing to?

```
static struct node* head = NULL;

int length()
{
    int counter = 0;

    struct node *cursor = head;

    if(cursor)
    {
        while((*cursor).next)
        {
            cursor = (*cursor).next;
            counter++;
        }    
    }

    free(cursor);

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: While valid `(*cursor).next` is somewhat unconventional syntax equivalent to `cursor->next`.  I'd stick with the conventional - especially if you are going to ask others to read your code.  Note also that when you call `free()`, `cursor` is no longer pointing to `head`.  It will return the memory used by the last node (tail) to the heap - and that is not actually whet you want to do here - that should only be done in functions that remove the node from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see from your code, once you delete `cursor` the last element from the list will be also deleted.
May be, you don't really need to call `free` in the `length` method cause methods such `length` shouldn't modify data the're working on.
I want to mention, that `cursor` is a simple pointer, so the memory for `cursor` is allocated on the stack and released automatically after method finishing. It's not an object allocated on the heap, it's only **pointer**, so you shouldn't care about any memory releasing.
Also pay attention to check that `cursor` is not `NULL` before the dereferencing.

Comment: Is there a way to free the memory that cursor is taking up?

Comment: @KylerBrown cursor does not use it's own memory. It is wrong to `free(cursor)`, because you delete memory from the linked list, without removing the element from the linked list.

Comment: @KylerBrown : It is not taking up any memory, it is merely a reference to memory that already exists.  You should not free this memory at all here.  The `cursor` pointer itself (not the memory it points to) is allocated on the stack and is recovered when it goes out of scope when the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

If two pointers have the same value that is they both point to the same object and one pf the pointers was freed then the other pointer will have an invalid value because the object it points to does not already exist.

As for your function then it is wrong.

There is no any need to free pointer `cursor`. I think the function should count nodes in the list. In this case even if the list contains only the head that is not equal to NULL then it also must be count.

The function can look the following way

static struct node* head = NULL;

```
int length()
{
    int counter = 0;

    for ( struct node *cursor = head; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->next )
    {
        ++counter;
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You free a memory address, not the variable itself.

Answer (score 0):

Once a pointer is free'd, accessing its former elements with the original pointer or a copy of that pointer, printing the pointer, copying the pointer, etc are all undefined behavior.

Will the original data disappear? Maybe, maybe not - it is UB.

Security concern: should a pointer point to sensitive data, `free(pointer)` does not not necessarily obliterate access to the data.  Code should scrub the data before freeing.  Other issues apply too.